# Jqueryui Drag and drop remove list icon

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I followed this tutorial to implement a drag and drop.

[authorcode.com](http://www.authorcode.com/drag-and-drop-li-elements-into-textbox/)

But when I drag an item, it shows a bullet. I want to remove it while dragging. I set "`list-style-type: none`" to the list as well. But still the bullet is visible while dragging. Please let me know how to remove that.

Comment: always provide your piece of code. We can not guess your implementation.

Comment: @TechBreak . All codes are in that link mentioned in the question. I didn't try to past all here again.

Answer (score 0):

try this it may help

```
li.ui-draggable-dragging {
list-style:none;
}
```